# Whats wrong with this bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R}, <)$ be a well ordering on the reals. Let $R_1$ be the minimal element in this ordering. Let $R_2$ be the minimal element in the set $\mathbb{R} - \{R_1\}$. Continue this process so that $R_i$ is the minimal element of $\mathbb{R} - \{R_1,R_2,...,R_{i-1}\}$ under $<$.

Now form the obvious bijection $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x) = R_x$.

**Obviously there exists no bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ so where does this go wrong?**

Comment: How is it obvious it's a bijection? In particular, it is not obvious at all that it is surjective (and false even).

Comment: Well presumably every real number is the minimal element of some subset of the reals. By extracting elements one by one it is intuitively obvious that every real will be some $R_i$. This is obviously not rigorous at all but what exactly prevents the reals from being enumerated in this way?

Comment: "Every real number is the minimal element of some subset of the reals" Obviously. In particular, $x$ is the minimal element of $\{x\}$. "By extracting elements one by one it is intuitively obvious that every real will be some $R_i$" this is not obvious, nor is it true. It is not true precisely because $\Bbb{R}$ is uncountable.

Comment: I second Zachary Selks comment. You claim that $\mathbb{R} - \cup_{n\in{\mathbb N}}\{R_1\dots R_n\} = $ the empty set is an obvious equality. It's not, and you should provide a proof for this.

Comment: Note the *petitio principi* involved in indexing the elements of your enumeration with positive integers.

Comment: Well-order $X = \{0,1\} \times\mathbb{N}$ by declaring $(a,m) < (b,n)$ if and only if $a = 0 \land b = 1$ or $a = b \land m < n$. Try the same for $X$, what goes wrong for $\mathbb{R}$ is the same, only more so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bijection since it is not surjective.

After an infinite number of steps, you still won't have go through all the reals numbers.